# Get object from JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to query a JSON file in my own server using `$.getJSON` and then cycling inside the objects. No problem so far, then i have an ID which is the name of the object i want to return, but can't seem to get it right:

```
  var id = 301;
  var url = "path/to/file.json";
  $.getJSON( url, function( json ) {
    var items = [];
    items = json;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      console.log(item);
    }
  });
```

This prints the following in the console:

[image: console.log of all the objects in json]

Now let's say i want return only the object `==` to `id` so then i can refer to it like `item.banos`, `item.dorms` etc.

My first approach was something like

```
console.log(json.Object.key('301'));
```

Which didn't work

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(json['301']));`

Comment: @jcubic anwer it, that's it

Comment: @KingRider please use English.

Comment: @jcubic that returns undefined

Comment: i know, a problem just number is not support to value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your response is wrapped in an array with one element.

---

You can access object properties dynamically via square brackets:

```
var id = 301;
var url = "path/to/file.json";
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    console.log(json[0][id].banos);
});
```

Comment: This did it, care to explain a bit on why do i have to use square brackets twice?

Comment: `[0]` accesses the first (and in this case only) element in the wrapping array. `[id]` accesses the property `id` of the object extracted from the array in the first step.

Comment: should i unwrap the array?

Comment: @TimoSta problem json is different object. Ur code example is correct.

Comment: @user2770956 That is kind of what `[0]` does. If you remove the array from the response on the server side, you don't have to do it in JavaScript -- if that is what you meant.

Comment: @KingRider Not sure what you are trying to say?

Comment: @TimoSta im developer dom advanced, i say code example is correct. i not help more... look a Gothdo is link to learn.

Comment: @KingRider what are you on about?

Answer (score 1):

As you have the name of the property in the object you want to retrieve you can use bracket notation. you can also simplify your code because of this:

```js
var id = 301;

//$.getJSON("path/to/file.json", function(json) {
  // response data from AJAX request:
  var json = {
    '301': {
      banos: 2
    },
    '302': {
      banos: 3
    },
    '303': {
      banos: 4
    },
    '304': {
      banos: 5
    },
  };

  var item = json[id];
  console.log(item);
//});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this returns undefined. Also i didn't downvote.

Comment: I added a working example. If this code doesn't work, then you need to add your actual JSON to the question, not an image of the console representation of it.

Comment: @KingRider sorry, I have no idea what you're saying

Comment: @KingRider kinda difficult to understand you, bro

Comment: @KingRider I'm not sure if you are serious or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(items,function(n,value){
    if(n==301)
        alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer as this post has been found in low quality post. Code only and 'try this' answers are discouraged as it doesn't provide any searchable content and why people should 'try this'.